# modify remote path in an android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run a sample android game in android studio.I'm asked to change the package name.I've changed it from com.google.example.games.tq to com.xxx.games.tq in manifest file(in both attributes, in manifest package, as well as in activity name)

I've created new directory hierarchy as per above package, then copied tq contents from old folder to new folder & then deleted the folders from old hierarchy.All package & import statements are also refactored.

However, when I run the project,it does this:

```
Uploading file
local path: E:\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\TrivialQuest\build\outputs\apk\TrivialQuest-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.google.example.games.tq
Installing com.google.example.games.tq
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.google.example.games.tq"
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a          security risk. Please fix.
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.google.example.games.tq
Success
Launching application:     com.google.example.games.tq/com.xxx.games.tq.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n   "com.google.example.games.tq/com.xxx.games.tq.MainActivity" -a    android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a  security risk. Please fix.
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat= [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]   cmp=com.google.example.games.tq/com.xxx.games.tq.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.google.example.games.tq/com.xxx.games.tq.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Please help me find how to resolve this error.Any idea how 'remote path' can be changed.it seems that remote path still has older path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I tried many other solutions but Clearing the cache and restart worked for me.

Go to Android Studio's File menu and select Invalidate Caches / Restart... option

Comment: I left the project halfway.But I'll accept this answer because it worked for you.